# How to show drop down result based on selected radio button | JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

I'm trying to write a JSP page where it needs to display a drop-down list of states based on the select country radio button on the same page. When I run the page it is displaying c:otherwise dropdown even after selecting the USA radio button. Please help

```
USA:<html:radio property="country" value="country" >
<c:set var ="p" value="usa"/>
</html:radio>

Germany:<html:radio property="country" value="country" >
<c:set var ="p" value="germany"/>
</html:radio>

<br>
list:
<c:choose>
<c:when  test = "${p == processors }" >

//drop down for states in USA
</c:when>
<c:otherwise >
//drop down for states in germany
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
enter code here
```

Comment: The `<c:set` and `<c:when` is executed only in the moment, the result page get's rendered. The radio button is active, after the page is rendered and sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to propagate your user's selection to the server side somehow, because with JSP, you can primarily do this in this way. A working example:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Reading Radio Buttons</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Reading Radio Buttons</H1>
        <%
            boolean radio2checked = false;
            if(request.getParameter("radios") != null) {
                if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("radio1")) {
                    out.println("Radio button 1 was selected.<BR>");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("Radio button 1 was not selected.<BR>");
                }
                if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("radio2")) {
                    out.println("Radio button 2 was selected.<BR>");
                    radio2checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    out.println("Radio button 2 was not selected.<BR>");
                }
            }
            pageContext.setAttribute("showUSAdropdown", radio2checked);
            String checked = radio2checked ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "";
        %>
        <FORM name="radioform" METHOD="post">
             <INPUT TYPE="radio" onclick="document.radioform.submit()" NAME="radios"     VALUE="radio1" CHECKED>
             Radio Button 1
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="radio" <%=checked%> onclick="document.radioform.submit()" NAME="radios" VALUE="radio2">
             Radio Button 2
            <BR>
            States:
            <SELECT name="states">
             <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${showUSAdropdown}">
                    <option>Alabama</option>
                    <option>Washington</option>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <option>Germany</option>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
            </SELECT>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: However this can be done in client side only using Javascript, the code above not belongs to the current/modern solutions.